# Need the ListBoxItem that spawned the Context Menu

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu, listboxitem

There are similar questions, but as I will explain, their answers do not seem to work for me.

I have a Listbox with an ItemsSource feeding it data...

```
<ListBox Name="lbPatternResults" SelectionMode="Multiple">
    <ListBox.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Get current values" Click="GetCurrentValuesForID"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </ListBox.ContextMenu>
</ListBox>
```

The ItemsSource property is set elsewhere to an IEnumerable.

When clicking the menuitem, the sender is the `MenuItem`, and its parent is the `ContextMenu`. Usually, to get the `ListBoxItem`, people are told to use the context menu's `PlacementTarget`, but in my case it's not a `ListBoxItem`... it's the `ListBox`. How do I get from here? I just want the index or the value of the row in the list...

EDIT: It's not the SelectedIndex of the ListBox (There can be one selected index, and one other that you get the menu from).

Comment: have you tried adding your `ContextMenu` to your `DataTemplate` of `ListBoxItem` instead of the `ListBox` and then using `PlacementTarget`?

Comment: I tried something like that. Got XAMLParseException saying the ContextMenu can not have a Visual or Logical Parent.

Comment: I've added a small example that works fine for me. Try that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine for me:

```
<ListBox>
  <ListBox.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="MyContextmenu">
      <MenuItem Click="MenuItem_OnClick"
                Header="Test" />
    </ContextMenu>
  </ListBox.Resources>
  <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
      <Setter Property="ContextMenu"
              Value="{DynamicResource MyContextmenu}" />
    </Style>
  </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
  <ListBoxItem Content="A" />
  <ListBoxItem Content="B" />
  <ListBoxItem Content="C" />
  <ListBoxItem Content="D" />
  <ListBoxItem Content="E" />
</ListBox>
```

and code-behind:

```
private void MenuItem_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
  var menuItem = (sender as MenuItem);

  if (menuItem == null)
    return;
  var parentMenu = menuItem.Parent as ContextMenu;

  if (parentMenu == null)
    return;
  var lbItem = parentMenu.PlacementTarget as ListBoxItem;
  if (lbItem != null)
    MessageBox.Show((string)lbItem.Content);
}
```

Comment: And what if you remove the `<ListBoxItem Content="x" />`, and use ItemsSource instead?

Comment: @SamiHuutoniemi well try it. How long does it take to test that out (It does work and I've tried it)

Comment: I missed the important part of your example :) This worked as long as removed the Items. Thanks!

Comment: Although this answer is accepted, I am still facing an issue whereby the PlacementTarget of the ContextMenu is the _ListBox_ and not the ListBoxItem. Therefore it is not possible for me to find which ListBoxItem created the ContextMenu. Can anyone else replicate this issue?